# Connection Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: python, flask, runtime-error, steam-web-api

I'm developing some software in python that utilizes Steam APIs. I'm using Flask to run and test the python code. Everything was going swell, but now I'm getting this error (I haven't changed any code):

> ('Connection aborted.', error(10060, 'A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond'))

I have no idea why this error is coming up, because the code was working perfectly fine and suddenly the error comes up, and I haven't changed anything in the code or with my computer or Flask.

The code:

```
import urllib
import itertools
import urllib2
import time
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import Flask
import requests
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
import sys


app = Flask(__name__)
API_KEY = 'XXX'
API_BASEURL = 'http://api.steampowered.com/'
API_GET_FRIENDS = API_BASEURL + 'ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key='+API_KEY+'&steamid='
API_GET_SUMMARIES = API_BASEURL + 'ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key='+API_KEY+'&steamids='
PROFILE_URL = 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'
steamIDs = []
myFriends = []

class steamUser:
    def __init__(self, name, steamid, isPhisher):
        self.name = name
        self.steamid = steamid
        self.isPhisher = isPhisher

    def setPhisherStatus(self, phisher):
        self.isPhisher = phisher

@app.route('/DeterminePhisher/<steamid>')
def getFriendList(steamid):
    try:
        r = requests.get(API_GET_FRIENDS+steamid)
        data = r.json()
        for friend in data['friendslist']['friends']:
            steamIDs.append(friend['steamid'])
        return isPhisher(steamIDs)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        return str(e.message)

def isPhisher(ids):
    phisherusers = ''
    for l in chunksiter(ids, 50):
        sids = ','.join(map(str, l))
        try:
            r = requests.get(API_GET_SUMMARIES+sids)
            data = r.json();
            for i in range(len(data['response']['players'])):
                steamFriend = data['response']['players'][i]
                n = steamUser(steamFriend['personaname'], steamFriend['steamid'], False)
                if steamFriend['communityvisibilitystate'] and not steamFriend['personastate']:
                    url =  PROFILE_URL+steamFriend['steamid']+'?xml=1'
                    dat = requests.get(url)
                    if 'profilestate' not in steamFriend:
                        n.setPhisherStatus(True);
                        phisherusers = (phisherusers + ('%s is a phisher' % n.name) + ', ')
                    if parseString(dat.text.encode('utf8')).getElementsByTagName('privacyState'):
                        privacy = str(parseString(dat.text.encode('utf-8')).getElementsByTagName('privacyState')[0].firstChild.wholeText)
                        if (privacy == 'private'):
                            n.setPhisherStatus(True)
                            phisherusers = (phisherusers + ('%s is a phisher' % n.name) + ', ')
                elif 'profilestate' not in steamFriend:
                    n.setPhisherStatus(True);
                    phisherusers = (phisherusers + ('%s is a phisher' % n.name) + ', ')
                else:
                    steamprofile = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(PROFILE_URL+steamFriend['steamid']).read())
                    for row in steamprofile('div', {'class': 'commentthread_comment  '}):
                        comment = row.find_all('div', 'commentthread_comment_text')[0].get_text().lower()
                        if ('phisher' in comment) or ('scammer' in comment):
                            n.setPhisherStatus(True)
                            phisherusers = (phisherusers + ('%s is a phisher' % n.name) + ', ')
                myFriends.append(n);
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            return str(e.message)
        except:
            return "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    return phisherusers

def chunksiter(l, chunks):
    i,j,n = 0,0,0
    rl = []
    while n < len(l)/chunks:        
        rl.append(l[i:j+chunks])        
        i+=chunks
        j+=j+chunks        
        n+=1
    return iter(rl)

app.run(debug=True)
```

I would like to have an explanation of what the error means, and why this is happening. Thanks in advance. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this is not the flask error, Its basically python socket error

as 10060 seems to be a timeout error, is it possible the server is very slow in accepting and
if the website opens in your browser,then there is possibility your browser has higher timeout threshold?

try increasing request time in request.get()

if the remote server is also under your access then :
You don't need to bind the socket (unless the remote server has an expectation of incoming socket) - it is extremely rare that this would actually be a requirement to connect.

Comment: I am using a local server off of my computer. How in python do I increase the request time?

Comment: requests.get("http://github.com", timeout=5)
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts

Answer (score 4):

I think this because steamcommunity's server unstable or some internet problem..

Usually,you can't fix the net shake.But there're still some methods can help u.

First,when you catch the net error,you let your thread sleep one seconds and then try again!

Second,I suggest u use Flask-Cache for this, such as cached 60 seconds,this will help u reduce http request.

Comment: Thank-you for that suggestion. I am basically new to flask do how would I accomplish that through code.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, those "connected party did not responde after a period of time", specially when the same code used to work before, are usually related to MTU sizes. Usually you should just [determine the maximum MTU size](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/5793) (don't forget to add 28 bytes as explained in the link) and then you can [change the MTU size](http://my.bergersoft.net/2010/05/13/how-to-change-mtu-size-on-windows-xpvista72008/) in your client computer.